# How to start vnc on boot

Tags: raspbian, vnc

I tried to make a script which start `x11vnc` at boot but it don't seem to work.

The script path:  `/home/pi/.config/autostart/x11vnc.desktop`

with the following contents:

```
[DESKTOP ENTRY]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=X11VNC
Comment=
Exec=x11vnc -forever -usepw -display :0 -ultrafilexfer
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Do you have any error messages or some logs that might be useful to answer?

Comment: Hello and thank you, no I haven't get any error message or logs

Answer (score 1):

Display :0 is used by the Console session. Starting x11vnc with -display :1 should then use a new display session and work correctly. 
 Remember you will need to tell your viewer to connect to :1 (or ::5901) to connect to this session.

Comment: I want to use the current desktop session is the reason why I use -display :0. Everything work fine when I execute the command from the terminal but when I try to automatically boot the script nothing happen

Comment: Which method are you using to automatically run the command? If you are running it while the runlevel is too low (when there is no X server running) then it would not work.